# java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform)

Tags: java, tomcat7, birt

I am trying to deploy birt runtime with tomcat. I am getting following error

> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart SEVERE:
>   Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of
>   class org.eclipse.birt.report.listener.ViewerServletContextListener
>   java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
>   org/eclipse/core/runtime/Platform : Unsupported major.minor version
>   51.0 (unable to load class org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform)
>           at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2908)
>           at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1173)
>           at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1681)
>           at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
>           at org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.jar.ServicePlatform.getExtensionRegistry(ServicePlatform.java:72)
>           at org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.jar.ServicePlatform.createFactoryObject(ServicePlatform.java:98)
>           at org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.Platform$1.run(Platform.java:297)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.Platform.createFactoryObject(Platform.java:293)
>           at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.setEngineContext(ReportEngineService.java:338)
>           at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.BirtViewerReportService.setContext(BirtViewerReportService.java:1023)
>           at org.eclipse.birt.report.listener.ViewerServletContextListener.contextInitialized(ViewerServletContextListener.java:62)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

I checked both runtime and compile time java versions.Both are pointing to same version
But still i am getting same error
Somebody,Can help me in resolving it ?

Comment: Either you are running code with an older version to the one you think, or you use a library in an older version compared to which it is compiled, or your tomcat doesn't support the Java version you're using. I don't see much else that might be causing this

Comment: This is usually due to running code in an earlier JVM -- i.e. you built using Java8 but the JVM on the deployed server is Java6 or 7.

Comment: Refer to this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0-error?rq=1

Comment: @Stultuske Can you please explain in detail....

Comment: @Bharath: those are the details. somewhere you have a class you are trying to run in an older version of Java compared to the one in which it has been compiled.

Comment: From BIRT 4.5, it appears java 6 is not supported anymore by a few eclipse libraries. Upgrade your java version should sove the problem